# Visual Studio 2019 build doesn't complete

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.9.4. Suddenly I am not able to build a particular WPF .NET Framework  project anymore. The build starts, but never finishes (tried waiting for 30min). I tried:

- Cleaning solution
- Deleting .vs folder
- Deleting VS temp folders
- Deleting the project completely and cloning from GitLab

but nothing helped. The next day the same issue occured to another WPF .NET Framework. I created an identical WPF .NET Standard project using dotnet CLI, but the project still cannot be built in Visual Studio, although `dotnet build` works fine. I also tried creating a default .NET Console project and building it with Visual Studio which also is not building.
Did anybody face a similar issue and has a solution?

Comment: `16.9.4` is old. Why aren't you running `16.11.5` (released today, in fact: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.11.5 )

Comment: Deleting your `.vs` and `obj` directories won't make a build go any faster. Instead enable verbose MSBuild logging and look at the Output window.

Comment: I'd gladly, but the company "approved" only 16.9.4 so far :(
I set verbosity to diagnostic, but didn't notice any errors

Comment: Then create a VM and install 16.11.5 and see if that fixes it in there - if it does work, then petition your company's IT people to update their asinine version policy. While they're investigating the issue I strongly recommend you send out your resume to companies that don't arbitrarily restrict their own employees. (I appreciate having a known-good-version policy _can be a good thing_ but what you're describing sounds like a horrible "do-as-we-say" policy, so my advice is to _get out of there_)